# Loading of data before angular 2 loads router-outlets

Tags: javascript, rest, angular

I am using Angular 2 release version.

During app initialisation, I need to call a service that fetches user and menu related information.

Since user related information is required by all the components, I was using *ngIf to only show div containing router-outlet once the data is loaded successfully. But this was working with deprecated router, now because of race condition, angular throws an error saying not able to find the router-outlet tag to switch between components.

How to handle such a scenario?

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#resolve-guard

Comment: I have tried using this and it works, but I have to use it for almost all the routes since I require user information for every component... This results in subscribing to the routes data and will result in additional 3-4 lines of code..
Is there any better way to fetch user information for every component like just writing getUser() without any subscriptions?

Comment: You can provide the data in a shared service, then you just need to inject the service.

Comment: Can you guide me with an example?

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service